# Moving bits to left

Tags: java

```
    byte right =0xf; // 00001111
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(right)); // 00001111

    right = (byte)(right << 4);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(right)); // 11111111111111111111111111110000
```

why `right` is equal to `11111111111111111111111111110000`? I explicitly cast it to byte = 8 bits.

I'm excpecting for an output: `11110000`.

Comment: Yup, you explicitly cast it to byte, then implicitly cast it back to int.  It's the latter step that backfilled it with ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you *hadn't* cast to `byte`, all would be well.

There are no shift operators defined for `byte`, so the value is first promoted to `int` - which is fine, and still 0000[...]1111.

You then shift left 4 bits, giving 0000[...]111000.

You then cast to `byte`, giving a byte of 11110000.

You then call `Integer.toBinaryString`, which takes an `int` parameter. That means the byte 1111000 is convert to `int` - at which point it's sign-extended to 11111111111111111111111111110000 (as per [JLS 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)), which is then printed.

Options:

- Don't cast down to `byte`, so you don't end up with a conversion back to `int`. (e.g. use `int shifted = right << 4;` and then pass `shifted` into `Integer.toBinaryString`.)
- Instead of leaving the conversion implicit, use `right & 0xff` to apply a bit-mask so you can *only* have the bottom 8 bits set.

Either of those prints 11110000 instead.